# Find all text files with Linux line endings

Tags: git, newline

I want to use Windows line endings (CRLF) for all of my source files but sometimes Linux line endings get mixed in, e.g. when Git is not properly configured.

How can I easily find all text files which have Linux line endings (LF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well readable solution using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) is:

```
 find . -not -path '*/.*' -type f | xargs file | grep text | grep -v CRLF
```

Explanation:

- `-not -path '*/.*'`: Filter out all directories starting with `.` (e.g. `.git` and `.vs`)
- `-type f`: Consider only files (not directories)
- `xargs file`: Apply `file` command to determine the file type
- `grep text`: Only consider text files (`file` includes string `text` for all of them)
- `grep -v CRLF`: Filter out files with Windows line ending

Note: To find all files with Windows line endings, just remove the `-v`:

```
find . -not -path '*/.*' -type f | xargs file | grep text | grep CRLF
```

Comment: Doesn't "grep CRLF" just grep for the string "CRLF"?

Comment: Yes, that is what `file` outputs for files with Windows line endings and will thus return all "CRLF" files.